# lscc chaincode timeout error

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a setup, which was working until today. Since morning I 'm not able to create new channels or install new chaincodes. Existing chaincodes are working.
Getting lscc chaincode timeout error when trying to install new chaincodes or create new channel.

Here are the logs, can someone please help?

```
2018-07-18 05:44:59.527 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 0d0 [][51efedf7] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:919
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:253
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:239
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:179
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
error sending
failed to execute transaction 51efedf7934af10cc3d6627c85262df4542d3186127c94f2a7156bb0111b2f72
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:181
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
```

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: No! created a new setup. Did waste about a week to fix it. Nothing worked.

Comment: can you add the version, sdk and chaincode languages? also reproduced in v1.3 Java chain codes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982837/problem-about-instantiating-java-chaincode-in-hyperledger-fabric-v1-3-failed-t/53221489#53221489