# Problem about instantiating Java chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric v1.3 - Failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, instantiation

I have a problem while instantiating the Chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric v1.3.

In the tutorial 'Building your first network' on the official website of Hyperledger Fabric, the java chaincode was successfully instantiated without any problems.

However, When I created a chaincode that I made myself, the following lscc error is occurring:

[Screenshot of exception stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAxz8.png)

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ljf.png)

Comment: Added captions for screenshots, removed the "please help me" line as it is clear what the author wants in this post, improved some minor spelling and grammar mistakes.

Comment: Please add the stack trace and error message directly in your post as text, not only as a screenshot. That way, other people with the same problem searching for the messages on the net might get routed to this question.

Comment: Having the same issue here, I am able to install with the Java SDK (without a chaincode path) but on instantiation I get the same timeout error message. I will open an issue and keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced the same problem v1.3 Java SDK + Java Chaincode instantiation :) several times, GO chain code works just fine. Probably a bug with Java chain code compatibility instantiation.

```
2018-11-08 18:48:25,798 main ERROR Channel:4103 - Sending proposal to peer1.domain.com failed because of timeout(120000 milliseconds) expiration
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4086)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendInstantiationProposal(Channel.java:2501)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdkintegration.End2endIT_custom_java.runChannel(End2endIT_custom_java.java:473)


2018-11-08 21:24:19.099 UTC [core/comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0a6 TLS handshake failed with error EOF {"server": "PeerServer", "remote address": "172.20.0.9:33462"}
2018-11-08 21:24:19.804 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 0a7 [channel][7c4fa0e2] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode SimpleChaincode:1 for transaction
```

Whereas go chain code works perfectly fine, no other difference in code
Install works fine, instantiate Java chaincode always times out
2018-11-08 20:48:27.686 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 031 Installed Chaincode [SimpleChaincode] Version [1] to peer

Reproducible again and again only with java chaincode instantiation with same logs, go chaincode instantiate works fine:
https://hastebin.com/osafazisaj.rb

when I switch from Kafka to SOLO orderer, I get a better and different exception, as occassionally Kafka orderer would freeze causing docker network saturation?
Switching to SOLO throws the error: 
failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction

https://hastebin.com/konoqewofe.md